# Migrating from TFS 2010 to TFS 2012

Tags: migration, team-foundation-server

We have just created a new Windows Server 2012 with TFS 2012 using a SQL Server 2012 db. I need to migrate the code with history from a TFS 2010 using SQL Server 2008 RS to this new server. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13711318/tfs-2010-moving-to-another-server-x64-and-update-to-tfs-2012

See Stack Overflow question there.  It links to the MSDN page with walkthroughs.  If you have questions during the migration or about the migration I would suggest asking over at SO as they would have more experience.

Comment: After a successful upgrade onto a the new server. The Team Project Collections screen shows my collections URL pointing to the old TFS. The SQL Server Instance is correct. Now everything works fine when connecting to the new TFS say from Visual Studio etc. Why is this URL line wrong on the General tab?

Comment: Did you move to a new server? If so, you may have to update the URL manually. Look at the bottom of this page. http://elhajj.wordpress.com/run-the-tfs-upgrade-wizard-rtm/